# Create ActiveRecord attributes without overriding select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using SQL's `AS` operator, we may create ActiveRecord attributes that don't correspond to a real column in our database:

```
user = User.select(<<-SQL).first
  *, CONTACT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name
SQL

user.full_name => "Bob Nastanovich"
```

My problem with this is that the `*` is necessary.  I'm writing an AR extension that will *add* virtual attributes for the result of a SQL computation, but including the `*` means that the user would never be able to narrow down the returned attributes using the `select` method.

Is there any way to add "calculated" attributes by some other method than `select` that also *ensures all the work is done by the database*?  I'm not looking to loop through the results post-query.  My example was very simple on purpose, the actual implementation involves computations on a `JOIN`.

I haven't been able to find anything about this so I'm skeptical, but I thought I'd ask!

Comment: You could probably override `ActiveRecord::Relation#exec_queries`, then check to see if `arel.projections` contains anything other than your library's values and then add the `*` to the projections, if not.

Comment: This would probably be very highly dependent on the Rails version, however.

Comment: Whoa, this is really interesting.  Definitely not a clean or ideal solution - especially since the computed attributes have variable names (well, semi-variable) - but I'm going to play around with this and let you know how it goes.  I'd already starting digging into the AR source and this has fast-tracked me whole a lot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same by just selecting just one field (any field would do):

```
> user = User.select(<<-SQL).first
>   id, CONTACT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name
> SQL

> user.full_name
 => "Bob Nastanovich"

> user
  => #<User id: 176488>

> user.attributes
 => {"id"=>176488, "full_name"=>"Bob Nastanovich"}
```

**EDIT**

The query works for me without the `*` as well:

```
> user = User.select(<<-SQL).first
>   CONTACT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name
> SQL

> user.full_name
 => "Bob Nastanovich"

> user
  => #<User id: nil>

> user.attributes
 => {"full_name"=>"Bob Nastanovich", "id"=>nil}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this will be in an AR extension, ie, it will be in library code.  I want to add the SQL computed attributes but also allow the user to use `select`.  If there is a `select("*")` in the library code, the select method essentially becomes useless to the user (other than adding other computed fields).

Comment: Without the `*`, the object would *only* contain the computed attributes.